# How to define the json schema for array of json objects in claimcenter

Tags: json, schema, guidewire, gosu

How to define the json schema for array of json objects .
How to write schema for this json example

example :

```json
[
 {
   "name" : "amy",
   "Age"   : "25" 
 },
 {
   "name" : "john", 
   "Age"   : "20"
 }
]
```

Tried in different ways but not working.

Comment: Could you share what you tried, and in why you say that it's not working?

Comment: {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "ClaimDetails": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "description": "List of all Claimant details",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "description": "name of the claimant",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "age": {
              "description": "age of the claimant",
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}API definition is not loading in swagger-ui for the above

Comment: I'm able to achieve below sample json
{
  "ClaimPayments": [
    {
      "Checknum": "1234567",
      "losscode": "1345"
    },
{
      "Checknum": "098765432",
      "losscode": "0000"
    }
 ]
} 
using below schema
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "ClaimDetails": {
      "properties": {
       "ClaimPayments": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/claiminfo"
}
}}
},"claiminfo" : {
  "properties": {
  "Checknum" : {
  "type": "string"
},"losscode": {
  "type": "string"
}}}}}